# Magento 2 add row total column in grid

Tags: magento2, grid, totals, column

I want to add row total of column in grid,I need hint/suggestion.I used this tutorial for creating a grid in magneto2
https://ranasohel.me/2014/04/20/creating-magento2-adminhtml-grid/.
I used ui_component for creating a grid.Just I need a hint to add row total of column in bottom.column name is price.I need `price` column total in bottom of grid.

**app/code/Test/Testimonial/view/adminhtml/ui_component/testimonial_blog_listing.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">testimonial_blog_listing.testimonial_blog_listing_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">testimonial_blog_listing.testimonial_blog_listing_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">testimonial_blog_columns</item>
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="add" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="name" xsi:type="string">add</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add New testimonial</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/new</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="testimonial_blog_listing_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">PostGridDataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">testimonial_blog_listing_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">entity_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <container name="listing_top">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/toolbar</item>
                <item name="stickyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/sticky/toolbar</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <bookmark name="bookmarks">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">testimonial_blog_listing</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </bookmark>
        <component name="columns_controls">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="columnsData" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">testimonial_blog_listing.testimonial_blog_listing.testimonial_blog_columns</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/controls/columns</item>
                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">dataGridActions</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </component>
        <exportButton name="export_button">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">testimonial_blog_listing.testimonial_blog_listing.testimonial_blog_columns.ids</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </exportButton>
        <filterSearch name="fulltext">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">testimonial_blog_listing.testimonial_blog_listing_data_source</item>
                    <item name="chipsProvider" xsi:type="string">testimonial_blog_listing.testimonial_blog_listing.listing_top.listing_filters_chips</item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">testimonial_blog_listing.testimonial_blog_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.search</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </filterSearch>
        <filters name="listing_filters">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="columnsProvider" xsi:type="string">testimonial_blog_listing.testimonial_blog_listing.testimonial_blog_columns</item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">testimonial_blog_listing.testimonial_blog_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.filters</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="templates" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="filters" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="select" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/ui-select</item>
                                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">testimonial_blog_listing.testimonial_blog_listing.listing_top.listing_filters</item>
                        <item name="imports" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="visible" xsi:type="string">testimonial_blog_listing.testimonial_blog_listing.testimonial_blog_columns.${ $.index }:visible</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
                <item name="observers" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="column" xsi:type="string">column</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </filters>
        <massaction name="listing_massaction">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">testimonial_blog_listing.testimonial_blog_listing.testimonial_blog_columns.ids</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <action name="delete">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">delete</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="testimonial/blog/massDelete"/>
                        <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete items</item>
                            <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Are you sure you wan't to delete selected items?</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </action>
            <action name="disable">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">disable</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Disable</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="testimonial/blog/massDisable"/>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </action>
            <action name="enable">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">enable</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Enable</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="testimonial/blog/massEnable"/>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </action>
        </massaction>
        <paging name="listing_paging">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">testimonial_blog_listing.testimonial_blog_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.paging</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">testimonial_blog_listing.testimonial_blog_listing.testimonial_blog_columns.ids</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </paging>
    </container>
    <columns name="testimonial_blog_columns">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">testimonial_blog_listing.testimonial_blog_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current</item>
                </item>
                <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">testimonial_blog_listing.testimonial_blog_listing.testimonial_blog_columns_editor</item>
                        <item name="target" xsi:type="string">startEdit</item>
                        <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="0" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                            <item name="1" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">testimonial_blog_listing.testimonial_blog_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="root" xsi:type="string">columns.${ $.index }</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.${ $.storageConfig.root}</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <selectionsColumn name="ids">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">55</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </selectionsColumn>
        <column name="entity_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                    <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">ID</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="title">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Title</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="publish_date" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Publish Date</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="price">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Price</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <actionsColumn name="actions" class="SR\testimonial\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\PostAction">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
                    <item name="viewUrlPath" xsi:type="string">testimonial/blog/edit</item>
                    <item name="urlEntityParamName" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </actionsColumn>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

Comment: what is the issue are coming after adding your price column defined in above code?

Comment: Not any issue but how can I display total  of column in row ?

Comment: means , your row total are not display inside grid, right?

Comment: Means that how can I add new row total in grid in magento 2 because in magento 2 used XML ui_component to display grid column so how can I add row total

Comment: row total is your price column, right and you want to display price column inside your column, Is this right>

Comment: No I want to display total of price column In Row

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I find a solution.
I hope this can help you.

Find the row in your ui component js file where is write the item tag with name "component":

```
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
```

and change it like:

```
 <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">YourVendor_YourModule/js/grid/provider</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
```

The path of that js file is: `vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/grid/provider.js`

So the new path of your new custom js file will be: `app/code/YourVendor/YourModule/view/base/web/js/grid/provider.js`

Change the method "processData" in the way that let you calculate the total of the price column, for example like this:
CHECK MODIFIED CODE COMMENT.JUST CHECK `processData` function because just changed that function and other function copied from `vendor\magento\module-ui\view\base\web\js\grid/provider.js`

```
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'mageUtils',
    'uiElement',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/alert',
    'mage/translate'
], function ($, _, utils, Element, alert, $t) {
    'use strict';

    return Element.extend({
        defaults: {
            listens: {
                params: 'reload'
            }
        },

        /**
         * Initializes provider component.
         *
         * @returns {Provider} Chainable.
         */
        initialize: function () {
            utils.limit(this, 'reload', 300);
            _.bindAll(this, 'onReload');

            return this._super();
        },

        /**
         * Initializes provider config.
         *
         * @returns {Provider} Chainable.
         */
        initConfig: function () {
            this._super();

            this.setData({
                items: [],
                totalRecords: 0
            });

            return this;
        },

        /**
         *
         * @param {Object} data
         * @returns {Provider} Chainable.
         */
        setData: function (data) {
            data = this.processData(data);

            this.set('data', data);

            return this;
        },

        /**
         * Reloads data with current parameters.
         */
        reload: function () {
            this.trigger('reload');

            if (this.request && this.request.readyState !== 4) {
                this.request.abort();
            }

            this.request = $.ajax({
                url: this['update_url'],
                method: 'GET',
                data: this.get('params'),
                dataType: 'json'
            });

            this.request
                .done(this.onReload)
                .error(this.onError);
        },

        /* START MODIFIED CODE */
        processData: function (data) {
        var items = data.items;
        var total = 0;
        _.each(items, function (record, index) {
            record._rowIndex = index;
         total += parseFloat(record.price);//price is column of custom table
        });
        jQuery("#custom_total_value").text(total);
        return data;
    }, 
        /* END MODIFIED CODE */
        /**
         * Handles reload error.
         */
        onError: function (xhr) {
            if (xhr.statusText === 'abort') {
                return;
            }

            alert({
                content: $t('Something went wrong.')
            });
        },

        /**
         * Handles successful data reload.
         *
         * @param {Object} data - Retrieved data object.
         */
        onReload: function (data) {
            this.setData(data)
                .trigger('reloaded');
        }
    });
});
```

record is an object inside the collection which is printed in the grid.

After you can add a block in your layout file:

```
 <referenceContainer name="content">
        <uiComponent name="your_listing"/>
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="YourVendor_YourModuke::custom_total.phtml" />
    </referenceContainer>
```

Inside custom_total.phtml I write:

```
<span><b>Total</b></span> <span id="custom_total_value"></span>
```

So I can see a row down the grid where is printed the total.

To see the changes in the grid remove all static file and cache with the command:

```
rm -rf var/cache/* var/page_cache/* var/view_preprocessed/* pub/static/*
```

inside your root magento directory.

Then recompile static content:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy your_language
```

**EDIT:** Alternatively you can modify data object returned by processData method, adding another record with same attributes of a normal record but with totals as values. In this way probably you can have a new row inside the grid. I didn't try this solution but I think it will work.

Comment: Where I have to put above your XML code in testimonial_blog_listing.xml file ?

Comment: I tried but my custom grid just loading nothing display. When I replace "YourVendor_YourModule/js/grid/provider" this code by old code "Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider" again then it display normal correct grid but not display total row.what is fault ? i think we are close answer.plz help me

Comment: Yes you have to put the XML tags inside testimonial_blog_listing.xml file
Did you create the block and phtml file?. Did you compile static file and clean the cache?

Comment: you have to put your modified provider.js in app/code/Test/Testimonial/view/base/web/js/grid/provider.js and then remove pub/static/* and then recompile static content or magento cannot read your provider.js file

Comment: thank you very much.I accepted your answer.I changed code in my provider.js and copy from Magento_Ui provider.js  file and now it works and edited your answer.thank you again

Comment: you're welcome ;) I'm glad to help you

Comment: I want to do same thing in customer edit page, and i did not have ui_component created. My grid is coming from a PHP file so can i do that. You can consider suppose i need that in order grid in admin panel on customer edit page

Comment: Snce you do this in JS, I guess, thougm, that you sum only the visible columns. But what if you have a result set that does not fit into one "page"?