# Magento 2 add row total column in simple grid

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.2

I have created Simple custom grid without use of UI Component.

now, i need to display total end of the columns.

[image]

anyone know how we can add total in custom grid??

Comment: check this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117390/magento-2-add-row-total-column-in-grid or this one https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/14190/how-to-add-a-total-row-in-a-magento-grid will help you

Comment: @hitesh we are not using UI component for grid. in shared example they use UI component for display total

Answer (score 0):

Add a class level variable `$_countTotals` and set value `true`

```
protected $_countTotals = true;
```

And add function

```
public function getTotals()
{
    $totals = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject;
    $fields = array(
        'total' => 0,
        'total_weight' => 0,
        'carrier_price' => 0
    );
    foreach ($this->getCollection() as $item) {
        foreach($fields as $field=>$value){
            if($field == "position" || $field == "total_limit") {
                $fields[$field] += $item->getData($field);
            }
        }
    }
    //First column in the grid
    $fields['order_id']='Totals';
    $totals->setData($fields);
    return $totals;
}
```

**Note: Use array keys according to your grid**

Comment: this solution is not working.